# Logged out from facebook.com too while logging out from the site using fb login

Tags: facebook, yii

I have integrated facebook login in my site. I am using php-sdk.
**Scenario :** Logged in facebook.com in seperate tab and then log-in to my site using facebook.
Now while i logout from my site, i automatically also get logged out from facebook.com in another tab. This is generally not the case with other site integrated with facebook. I just want to destroy session from my site not the facebook.com .
Here is code
Login

```
     $response = file_get_contents($token_url); // get the token
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);
     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $params['access_token'];

     $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
```

Logout

```
 $fbLogoutUrl = 'https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=http://www.mysite.com'.Yii::app()->homeUrl.'&access_token='.$fbLogout->toke
$this->redirect($fbLogoutUrl);
```

I am storing the token and using it to logout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. Calling the logout function will log you out from both Facebook and your site. This is also true for the JavaScript SDK.

If you just want to log the user out of your site, destroy the session (`session_destroy()`) and delete the cookie set by Facebook on your site.

Comment: How to delete the cookies set by facebook ?

Answer (score 0):

I get issue same you, and i it was resolved

I use extension of [yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/facebook-opengraph/)

and in config of extension in file main i edit this line:

```
 //'status'=>true, // JS SDK - check login status
```

to

```
'status'=>false, // JS SDK - check login status
```

may be help you